# Can i always use class component and not use functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in ReactJS and I'm wondering what is the point of using stateless component(aka functional component) when we can use class base component even if we don't have state in our component? Is this just a convention? Or this is about our app speed!
Because, I always forget to remove render() method from my component when I'm trying to use functional component. Thank you.

Comment: Functional components can have state. Class-based components can be stateless. React has great documentation covering why they are pushing functional components and hooks. [Motivation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#motivation)

Comment: Best practice is actually to use functional components with state hooks. The concept of "stateless functional vs stateful class components" has been out of date since hooks were introduced in v16.8.